# Minimax tic tac toe isn't choosing actual best move

Tags: python, tkinter, artificial-intelligence, minimax

I wrote python code for a Minimax AI tic tac toe. However, the Minimax in action isn't actually picking the best move. It always seems to pick the upper right corner for the first move, and all other moves almost seem random. It is very easy to beat, which seems to be an error somewhere in my code. Thank you for any help.

GUI Code:

```
from tkinter import *
import customtkinter
import minimax

customtkinter.set_appearance_mode("Dark")
#creating CTk window for app
root = customtkinter.CTk()

#setting window width and height
root.geometry('500x300')


#Creating label
label = customtkinter.CTkLabel(master=root,
                               text="Tic Tac Toe",
                               width=120,
                               height=50,
                               font=("normal", 20),
                               corner_radius=8)
label.place(relx=0.25, rely=0.8, anchor=CENTER)

#Handling clicks
depth=9
def clickbutton(r, c):
    buttons[r][c]["text"]="X"
    board[r][c]="X"
    buttons[r][c]['state']=DISABLED

    label = customtkinter.CTkLabel(master=root,
                               text=checkwin(board),
                               width=120,
                               height=25,
                               corner_radius=8)
    label.place(relx=0.25, rely=0.9, anchor=CENTER)

    global depth
    depth-=1
    computerplay()
    depth-=1
    
    

#Button matrix
buttons = [
     [0,0,0],
     [0,0,0],
     [0,0,0]]
 
#Matrix identifying whether buttons are active or inactive
board=[[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0]]
 
for i in range(3):
    for j in range(3):                                 
        buttons[i][j] = Button(height = 3, width = 6, font = ("Normal", 20),
                        command = lambda r = i, c = j : clickbutton(r,c))
        buttons[i][j].grid(row = i, column = j)



def computerplay():
    global depth
    bestmove=minimax.minimax(board, depth, 1)
    buttons[bestmove[0]][bestmove[1]]['text']="O"
    buttons[bestmove[0]][bestmove[1]]['state']=DISABLED
    board[bestmove[0]][bestmove[1]]="O"

def checkwin(b):
    score=minimax.evaluate(b)
    if score==10:
        return 'Computer won!'
    elif score==-10:
        return 'You won!'
    else:
        return 'Player vs. Computer'
    

root.mainloop()
```

Minimax code:

```
def change_board(board):
    return [
        [(cell == "O") - (cell == "X") for cell in row]
        for row in board
    ]

def empty_cells(board):
    return [(i, j) for i in range(3) for j in range(3) if board[i][j] == 0]

def game_over(board):
    return (evaluate(board) == 10 or evaluate(board) ==-10 or not empty_cells(board))
    
lines = (
    (0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2),
    (0, 2, 1, 1, 2, 0),
    (0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 2),
    (1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2),
    (2, 0, 2, 1, 2, 2),
    (0, 0, 1, 0, 2, 0),
    (0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1),
    (0, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2)
)

def evaluate(board):
    def iswin(line):
        arow, acol, brow, bcol, crow, ccol = line
        if board[arow][acol] == board[brow][bcol] == board[crow][ccol]:
            return board[arow][acol]*10

    return next((win for win in map(iswin, lines) if win), 0)
    

def minimax(board, depth, player):
    best = (-1, -1, -11*player)

    if depth <= 0 or game_over(board):
        return (-1, -1, evaluate(board))  # must return same structure

    for x, y in empty_cells(board):
        board[x][y] = player
        score = minimax(board, depth - 1, -player)[2]  # only get the score
        board[x][y] = 0
        if (player == 1) == (score > best[2]):
            best = (x, y, score)  # only inject x, y when move is best

    return best
```

Comment: Your `evaluate` function seems strange to me. Does it mean that you have no heursitic? Either one of the player is winning, or not, and that's it?

Comment: Because then, that means that with a depth insufficient to reach winning position, all move are identical (and void). And with a depth sufficient enough likewise. Since you know that this game can't be won if your adversary is clever enough. And the postulate of minimax is precisely that the adversary is as smart as you are. So, no winning move, since there is a way to stop them.

Comment: Said otherwise, the only way a minimax can make sense for such a game, is if you limit the depth, and rely on some heuristic. So still sort moves, even if, in reality (and therefore, if you recurse all the way down to full board) all the moves worth exactly the same and leads to drawn. If you recurse only 4 move ahead, then, you can arbitrarily decide that a move that leads you to 2 aligned X and a possibility to fill the 3rd if the adversary fails to block you, is better than a move that give you no such opportunity.

Comment: That being said, it should not be easy to beat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is mixing up the values that it stores in `board`. On the one hand there is the minimax module which stores and expects values -1, 0 and 1 in `board` (as `player` is either 1 or -1), but on the other hand you have code on the GUI side that stores `"O"` or `"X"` in the board data structure. This mix up breaks the logic used in the `evaluate` function.

In your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75103694/5459839) on the subject, you had a function `change_board`, which performed a conversion from the `"X"` and `"O"` values to -1 and 1. But in this question this conversion is not performed.

So to fix this, change these lines in the GUI managing code:

```
board[r][c]="X"
...
board[bestmove[0]][bestmove[1]]="O"
```

...to:

```
board[r][c]=-1
...
board[bestmove[0]][bestmove[1]]=1
```